# What is the relation of the Infinite power series with these fraction series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Take this infinite series:
$$S = 1 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty\prod_{i=1}^n\frac{2i+1}{4i} = 1 + \frac{3}{4} + \frac{3\times5}{4\times8} + \frac{3\times5\times7}{4\times8\times12} + ....$$
We want to find the sum of this series. I didn't know how to solve this. But when I went to look at the solution, they compared this series with the infinite power series
$$P = (1+x)^n = 1 + nx + \frac{n(n-1)}{2!}x^2 + \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{3!}x^3 + ......$$
for some real $n$ and $x$. Equating the corresponding terms ($nx = \frac{3}{4}$ and $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}x^2 = \frac{3\times5}{4\times8}$) they found $n=-\frac{3}{2}$ and $x=-\frac{1}{2}$. So that the sum is simply $2^\frac{3}{2}$. And when I checked the infinite power series $P$ plugging these values of $x$ and $n$, it really turn out to be the series $S$. Now, I don't understand why this comparison works.
Let's generalise this thing. Say, $S$ is given by
$$S = 1 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty\prod_{i=1}^n\frac{ai+b}{di}$$
for some positive integers $a, b$ and $d$ with $b < a$, and it is guaranteed (given) that the series converges. Let $P$ be the same as above. Now, can anyone say if $S$, as defined just now, can always be compared with the series $P$, that is, are there always some real $n$ and $x$ such that $S = P?$

Comment: I don't think this generally works it just happens to be the case that$$\prod_{i=1}^n\frac{2i+1}{4i}=\binom{-3/2}{n}\left(-\frac12\right)^n$$

Comment: Sure about this? 'Cause the same problem with different numbers appear in our high school exams and they solve all of them this way.

Comment: Well they could just be choosing the values of the constants specifically so this approach works.

Comment: You're right. I think I need to edit a little. :)

Comment: $\displaystyle 2\,\sqrt{\, 2\,}\,$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that setting $nx=\frac{3}{4}$ and $\frac{n(n-1)}{2!}=\frac{3\cdot 5}{4\cdot 8}$ in order to get values for $n$  and $x$ is just a clever approach, but not a proof that $P=S$.

To make it a proof we have to additionally verify that the *general terms* evaluated at $n=\frac{3}{2}$ and $x=-\frac{1}{2}$ are equal.

> Let's write $S$ and $P$ with *general term*. We have
> \begin{align*}
> S&=1+\frac{3}{4}+\frac{3\cdot 5}{4\cdot 8}+\cdots+
> \color{blue}{\frac{3\cdot 5\cdots (2k+1)}{4\cdot 8\cdots (4k)}}+\cdots\tag{1}\\
> P&=(1+x)^n\\
> &=1+nx+\frac{n(n-1)}{2!}x^2+\cdots+\color{blue}{\frac{n(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1)}{k!}x^k}+\cdots\tag{2}
> \end{align*}
> We simplify the general term of $S$ somewhat
> \begin{align*}
> \frac{3\cdot 5\cdots (2k+1)}{4\cdot 8\cdots (4k)}&=\frac{1}{4^k}\cdot\frac{3\cdot 5\cdots (2k+1)}{1\cdot 2\cdots k}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{4^kk!}\prod_{j=1}^k(2j+1)}
> \end{align*}
> The general term of $P$ evaluated $n=\frac{3}{2}$ and $x=-\frac{1}{2}$:
> \begin{align*}
> &\left.\frac{n(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1)}{k!}x^k\right|_{n=-\frac{3}{2},x=-\frac{1}{2}}\\
> &\qquad\qquad=\frac{1}{k!}\left(-\frac{3}{2}\right)\left(-\frac{5}{2}\right)\cdots\left(-\frac{3}{2}-k+1\right)\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^k\\
> &\qquad\qquad=\frac{1}{k!}\frac{(-1)^k}{2^k}\left(3\right)\left(5\right)\cdots\left(3+2k-2\right)\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^k\\
> &\qquad\qquad\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{4^kk!}\prod_{j=1}^k(2j+1)}
> \end{align*}
> Since both terms are equal we can now conclude that $S=P$.

**Note:** In order to generalise this approach,  we could start to study and compare *general terms* accordingly.

**[Add-on (2020-07-08)]:** This add-on is based on OP who has successfully calculated the generalisation in comments to this answer.

The general ($k$-th) term of $S = 1 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty\prod_{j=1}^n\frac{aj+b}{dj}$ is (provided $a\ne 0$):
\begin{align*}
\prod_{j=1}^k\frac{aj+b}{dj}&=\frac{1}{d^kk!}\prod_{j=1}^k(aj+b)\\
&=\left(\frac{a}{d}\right)^k\frac{1}{k!}\prod_{j=1}^k\left(j+\frac{b}{a}\right)\tag{3}
\end{align*}
Since the general term of $P=(1+x)^n$ is
\begin{align*}
\frac{x^k}{k!}\prod_{j=1}^k(n-j+1)&=\frac{(-x)^k}{k!}\prod_{j=1}^{k}\left(j-\left(n+1\right)\right)\tag{4}
\end{align*}

we obtain by comparison of (3) with  (4):
\begin{align*}
x=-\frac{a}{d}\qquad\qquad n=-\left(1+\frac{b}{a}\right)
\end{align*}

> We conclude, providing $|x|=\left|\frac{a}{d}\right|<1$ to assure convergence of the *[binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series#Conditions_for_convergence)*:
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{S }= 1 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty\prod_{j=1}^n\frac{aj+b}{dj}\color{blue}{=\left(1-\frac{a}{d}\right)^{-\left(1+\frac{b}{a}\right)}}
> \end{align*}

**Hints:**

- Alternatively to OPs generalisation we can also recall that $P=(1+x)^n$ is some kind of *reference series* used to derive $S$. We can turn the tables and *play* with different settings of $x$ and $n$ (respecting $|x|<1$) and check which different *general terms* and series $S$ we obtain this way.
- A technical aspect. We have to be aware of arithmetic precedence rules and write $\prod_{j=1}^k\color{blue}{(}aj+b\color{blue}{)}$ using brackets, since  we have
  \begin{align*}
  \prod_{j=1}^kaj+b&=\left(\prod_{j=1}^kaj\right)+b=a^kk!+b\\
  \prod_{j=1}^kb+aj&=\left(\prod_{j=1}^kb\right)+aj=b^k+aj\\
  \prod_{j=1}^k\left(aj+b\right)&=(a+b)(2a+b)\cdots(ka+b)
  \end{align*}
  You might want to see *[this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2348132)* for more information regarding precedence rules.

Comment: Wow. Seeing this I tried the general form and arrived at this: $\frac{1}{d^k k!}\prod_{i=1}^k ai+b = \frac{x^k}{k!} \prod_{i=1}^k n-i+1$. Now I think I just need to express $n$ and $x$ in terms of $a, b$ & $d$, right?

Comment: Nice. It gives $n=-\frac{a+b}{a}$ and $x=-\frac{a}{d}$. And these formulas really work. XD Thanks a lot. And could you please add this generalization to your answer?

Comment: @Shajid: I will add some info after work. Regards,

Comment: alright. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Shajid: Some additional information added.

Comment: I'll be careful with the brackets next time on

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
S & \equiv 1 + \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}
\prod_{i = 1}^{n}{2i + 1 \over 4i} =
1 + \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{2^{n} \over 4^{n}}
{\prod_{i = 1}^{n}\pars{i + 1/2} \over n!} =
1 + \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over 2^{n}\, n!}\,
\pars{3 \over 2}^{\overline{\large n}}
\\[5mm] & =
1 + \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over 2^{n}\, n!}\,
{\Gamma\pars{3/2 + n} \over\Gamma\pars{3/2}} =
1 + \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over 2^{n}}\,
{\pars{n + 1/2}! \over n!\pars{1/2}!}
\\[5mm] & =
1 + \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over 2^{n}}\,{n + 1/2 \choose n} =
1 + \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over 2^{n}}
\bracks{{-3/2 \choose n}\pars{-1}^{n}}
\\[5mm] & =
1 + \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}
{-3/2 \choose n}\pars{-\,{1 \over 2}}^{n} =
1 + \braces{\bracks{1 + \pars{-\,{1 \over 2}}}^{-3/2} - 1}
\\[5mm] & =
\bbox[15px,#ffd,border:1px solid navy]{\large 2\root{2}}\ \approx\ 2.8284
\end{align}

Comment: Could you kindly clarify the $\overline{n}$ notation, i.e, the part: $\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{\overline{n}}$?

Comment: @Shajid $\displaystyle a^{\large\overline{n}} \equiv
a\left(a + 1\right)\left(a + 2\right)\cdots\left[a + \left(n - 1\right)\right]$

Comment: @Shajid See section ${\bf 2.6}$ in $Concrete\ Mathematics$ by R. L. Graham, D. E. Knuth and O. Patashnik, $2^{\underline{nd}}$ ed. Addison Wesley.

Comment: that 3rd line took me a while. I think that's a really strange yet amazing way to find the exact sum. :) thanks. And I'll certainly check out the book for more info